# When is an active QMainWindow window not really active?

Tags: c++, qt, focus, qwidget, qmainwindow

I have a Windows Qt application that creates a QMainWindow, dismisses (closes and deletes) it, and then creates a new QMainWindow. The new QMainWindow needs to do some setup whenever it is the 'active' window in the system, and needs to do some teardown whenever it is no longer the 'active' window in the system. What I'm really concerned about when I say 'active' is z-order - I want the QMainWindow to do the setup when it is highest in the desktop z-order, and teardown when it is no longer the highest in the z-order.

Curiously, Qt's concept of what an 'active' window is doesn't line up with the concept of z-order - when I detect window activation through QMainWindow::isActiveWindow(), QApplication::activeWindow(), or QEvent::WindowActivate, they don't always return negative when the window isn't the highest in z-order.

I have an example program that demonstrates this problem. It's very simple.

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    for ( int i = 10; i >= 0; --i )
    {
        QThread::sleep( 1 );
        qDebug( "%d...", i );
    }

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_textEdit = new QTextEdit( this );
    setCentralWidget( m_textEdit );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *e)
{
    switch ( e->type() )
    {
    case QEvent::WindowActivate:
        qDebug( "WindowActivate - I %s the active window!", qApp->activeWindow() == this ? "AM" : "AM NOT" );
        break;
    case QEvent::WindowDeactivate:
        qDebug( "WindowDeactivate" );
        break;
    default: break;
    }
    return QMainWindow::event(e) ;
}
```

ui_mainwindow.h is unchanged from the version that QtCreator makes for you with the default Qt application template.

Build and run this program from within QtCreator. It'll count down from 10 and then show the QMainWindow. If you don't do anything while it's counting down, the QMainWindow will appear above QtCreator, and on the console in QtCreator you'll see:

```
3...
2...
1...
0... WindowActivate - I AM the active window!
```

BUT, if during the countdown, you click on another window (an instance of notepad, maybe), taking the focus away from QtCreator, the QMainWindow will appear, but it won't be the highest in the z-order - notepad will be. BUT, the QMainWindow's window decorations will be highlighted (?!?) as if it were the active window, and on the console we get

```
3...
2...
1...
0... WindowActivate - I AM the active window!
```

...even though it clearly isn't the active window in the system - notepad is.

What's going on here? I'm seeing this with Qt 4.8.4 and 5.1.0 on Windows.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a bug in Qt. Qt assumes that the window is active on startup regardless of its real condition. You can use `GetForegroundWindow() == reinterpret_cast<HWND>(winId())` to check if the window is really active.

Comment: What happens when you run it outside of the debugger? Is the behavior different? You may have to change the qDebug statements to normal prints to know for sure. Also when you type on the keyboard, which window get keyboard input. If I had to guess based on your caret, the MainWindow still has keyboard focus, therefore Qt still thinks it is the active window.